# How to make the squares scroll in a row in a mobile view in html/css?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries, horizontal-scrolling

I have a screenshot below which I have replicated in the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/hpmawvy0/5/embedded/result/). In the fiddle I have a made a parent div in which I have mentioned all the 2 rows:

```
<div class="product-all-contents">

<div class="product-contents">
</div>

<div class="product-contents">
</div>

</div>
```

[image]

**Problem Statement:**

I want to make **the individual row scroll in the mobile/tablet view**. The CSS codes which I have tried in order to make it scroll are as follows be it doesn't seem to work. Do I need to set min-width as well in order to make the rows scroll in mobile/tablet view?

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
.product-all-contents
{
  overflow-x: auto;
}
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

- 1) You need to set `overflow-x` to `.product-contents` so that it shows
  scroll on smaller screen
- 2) Set `min-width` to `.product` so that it will not get smaller on small
  device
- 3) Using `:not` selector in `.product`, set `margin-right` so that space
  between each item will remain
- 4) Remove `white-space` from the `.product-all-contents` in `@media only
  screen and (max-width: 767px)` as there is no need of it now

```css
.product-contents {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  padding: 1rem;
  overflow-x: auto;
}
.product-contents .product {
  width: 10%;
  min-width: 90px;
  text-align: center;
  height: 150px;
  padding-top: 1%;
  padding-left: 1%;
  padding-right: 1%;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 3px;
  border-color: rgb(145, 147, 150);
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px
}
.product-contents .product:not(:last-child) {
    margin-right: 15px;
}
.product-contents .product img {
  max-width: 100%;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
.product-all-contents
{
  overflow-x: auto;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="product-all-contents">

<div class="product-contents">
  <div class="product"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="product"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="product"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="product"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="product"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="product"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="product"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="product"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" /></div>
</div>

<div class="product-contents">
  <div class="product"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="product"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="product"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="product"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="product"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="product"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="product"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" /></div>
  <div class="product"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/150x150" alt="" /></div>
</div>

</div>
```

Updated fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/utmyu5r6/9/)

Comment: I have created the fiddle for your answer. Although, I can see bit of scrolling but they are still intact. Do I need to increase the min-width ?

Comment: can you share the `fiddle` link?

Comment: you can set `min-width` for `product` for e.g. `150px`, its happening because you have given `percentage` for `width` in `product`

Comment: It looks good, but if you check now the space between the boxes is gone in mobile view in comparison to the desktop view it is still present.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171992/discussion-between-zuber-and-user5447339).

Comment: Yes it solved my problem, that's why I have accepted your answer. :)

Answer (score 2):

it's a good idea to fix height and width of a box instead of using width in percentage because of this layout of the page will be consistent on all screens and a user can also able to scroll individual product row horizontally

Just change your CSS rules as below I have changed your CSS rules of `.product` class and added one extra media query for the horizontal scroll in a product row.

```
.product-contents .product {
    min-width: 160px;
    width:160px;
    text-align: center;
    height: 150px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 3px;
    border-color: rgb(145,147,150);
    background-color: white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px)
{
  .product-contents{
     overflow-x: auto;
  }
}
```

Hope this work for you :)